# Output Capacitor Value

Tags: lipo

I am trying to choose my output capacitor for the TPS6107 boost converter. I am using the equation Io x D/ Fs x Delta Vout(Desired Output Voltage Ripple). I have found all the other values for the equation, but I am getting hung up on finding my output voltage ripple. Can someone help me understand this a little better?

Thanks

Comment: Probably, but not without all the missing information. Read your question again. You're missing the link to the datasheet, a circuit schematic and your work so far. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: My values are: Io= 380, D= .388, Fs= 1200

Comment: Data Sheet: http://www.ti.com/product/TPS61070/datasheet/application_and_implementation#SLVS5103348

Comment: I plan on using the circuit shown in the data sheet on

Comment: Pop all the information into the question so it's all in one place rather than sprinkled through the comments. You can post a screengrab of the schematic in the post too. It will attract a lot more attention from the busy guys who won't be inclined to follow the link to figure out what you've done. If you're really keen, the site supports [MathJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your equations.

Comment: Well you're supposed to decide on the max output voltage you want and then you choose the capacitor value depending on that...

Answer (score 0):

> My values are: Io= 380, D= .388, Fs= 1200

This doesn't seem right. You're saying that Iout = 380A, Duty Cycle = 38.8% and Fs = 1200Hz? That's what those values mean plugged into the equation.

Also, the output voltage is something that you spec out as a designer. This depends on how tight you want the converter to regulate. You could choose a ripple of say 1%. This would mean:

DeltaVout = 0.01 x Vout

Ror a 5V output you'd use 50mV (0.05) for the equation.